# Pull plugin "com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin" fail because "Failed to get access token from gcloud or Application Default Credentials"

Tags: gradle, google-cloud-platform

I included plugin "com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin" in my gradle project.

```
plugins {
......
id "com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin" version "2.1.1"
}
```

I always get an error message during pulling:

```
Failed to apply plugin 'com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin'.
Failed to get access token from gcloud or Application Default Credentials
```

Anyone knows why?
I see it mentioned in this post https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/artifact-registry-maven-tools/issues/34. that I need to have a GCP account first. I downloaded the GCP SDK, and logged in to my account, but still get the same message. Anyone can provide more specific solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I've not tried this**

Have a look at [Setting up Authentication for Grade](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/java/authentication#gradle) in Google's Artifact Registry docs.

Hopefully you can use the [credential helper](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/java/authentication#auth-helper)

[Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) is a very useful Google platform feature that simplifies obtaining credentials. Code (not `gcloud`) running:

- off-GCP (locally or e.g. GitHub|GitLab) can be configured to use credentials through an environment variable setting (`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`)
- on-GCP (e.g. Compute Engine) obtains the credentials automatically (e.g. Metadata service).

I suspect (!) that the Maven|Gradle plugins looks for `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in this way to authenticate (using a Service Account) your script to Google.

##### Update: Example

```sh
BILLING=[[YOUR-BILLING]]
PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]
REPO=[[YOUR-REPO]] # E.g. repo
LOCATION=[[YOUR-LOCATION]] # E.g. us-west2

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}

gcloud beta billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

# Enable Artifact Registry
gcloud services enable artifactregistry.googleapis.com \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Create Maven repository
gcloud artifacts repositories create ${REPO} \
--location=${LOCATION} \
--repository-format=maven \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Create Service Account to be used by gradle
ACCOUNT="gradle"
EMAIL=${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL}

# Export the Service Account key as Application Default Creds
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json

# Grant the Service Account permissions to Artifact Registry
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=roles/artifactregistry.admin

# Get the Gradle settings
# You'll need to manually merge these
gcloud artifacts print-settings gradle \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--repository=${REPO} \
--location=${LOCATION}
```

I use `./gradlew init` to create a basic Java app. I then tweaked the `build.grade`. I've not used Gradle much at all and so apologies if this is incorrect:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id "maven-publish"
    id "com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin" version "2.1.1"
}

publishing {
  publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
      groupId = "com.dazwilkin.test"
      artifactId = "application"
      version = "0.1"

      from components.java
    }
  }
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "artifactregistry://${LOCATION}-maven.pkg.dev/${PROJECT}/${REPO}"
    }
  }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
      url "artifactregistry://${LOCATION}-maven.pkg.dev/${PROJECT}/${REPO}"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'com.dazwilkin.test.App'
}
```

Then:

```sh
./gradlew publish

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
5 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

And:

```sh
gcloud artifacts packages list \
--repository=${REPO} \
 --location=${LOCATION} \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Yields:

```
Listing items under project [[PROJECT]], location [[LOCATION]], repository [[REPO]].

PACKAGE: com.dazwilkin.test:application
CREATE_TIME: 2021-12-09T17:34:19
UPDATE_TIME: 2021-12-09T17:44:20
```

Comment: Thanks DazWilkin! I notice that the plugin `com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin` is exactly the plugin that the [credential helper](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/java/authentication#auth-helper) suggested. I use `gcloud auth application-default login` and run `gradle build`, it downloaded the plugin successfully.

Comment: But then I have another problem, it complains `Could not GET https://us-maven.pkg.dev/<company-name>-dev/commons/token-validator/2.5/token-validator-2.5.pom. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Disable Gradle offline mode and sync project`. I disabled Grade offline mode, still didn't work. I wonder if `maven.pkg.dev` a repository from G Cloud? If yes, I guess it's just my G Cloud account doesn't have access permission to it?

Comment: I just tried this (not a Java|Gradle developer). It works ok for me. I suspect you should not use `gcloud auth application-default login`. This is a useful `gcloud` feature but it has some limitations and is discouraged. Please create a Service Account and set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. I'll update my answer with more context.

Comment: Thanks DazWilkin. I'm very new to G Cloud, so I may ask dumb questions, sorry about that. In my case, I download the code locally and hope to build and run it locally. My understanding is that the plugin and that dependency are not public but located in G Cloud repository, so I need to let Gradle know the GCloud credential, am I correct? The way I input the credential is to run `$export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json` in my terminal. Then when I run `$gradle build`, it'll automatically pick it as `environment variable`. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Everyone was a beginner at one time. There are **no** dumb questions please continue to ask questions. I'm happy to try to help!

Comment: I think the plugin etc. **are** public. You should not need a Google account to download them. The reason for creating the Service Account and using `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is because the Artifact Registry that you wish to use is private (as it should be) and you will need to provide credentials to Google to prove that you are permitted to e.g. add artifacts to it.

Comment: You are correct. The plugin and dependency are public. Just the Artifact Registry is private. By the way, can you be a little bit more specific about the JSON file for `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. Such as I have a user name `ABC`, password `123`, what would the content of the json file look like, and how about the name(I guess it can be anything we like?). I know you've already covered it in your example code. I just didn't understand all of them. Also, is it possible that I do `$gcloud auth login`, the credential then can automatically be in my `environment variable`?

Comment: A Service Account is a particular type of Google account. You cannot convert from username/password. If you'd prefer to use Cloud Console, you can create a Service Account, a Service Account key and assign permissions using it but, it's a little bit too involved to explain here. You can start at: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to authenticate using standard HTTPS + Basic auth, avoiding Gradle plugin with custom namespace `artifactregistry://` using magical users:

- `_json_key`
- `_json_key_base64`

See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/artifact-registry-maven-tools/issues/71